# Inconsistency in output field separator

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

We have to find the difference(d) Between last 2 nos and display rows with the highest value of d in ascending order
INPUT

```
1 | Latha | Third | Vikas | 90 | 91  
2 | Neethu | Second | Meridian | 92 | 94  
3 | Sethu | First | DAV | 86 | 98  
4 | Theekshana | Second | DAV | 97 | 100  
5 | Teju | First | Sangamithra | 89 | 100  
6 | Theekshitha | Second | Sangamithra | 99 |100
```

Required OUTPUT

```
4$Theekshana$Second$DAV$97$100$3  
5$Teju$First$Sangamithra$89$100$11  
3$Sethu$First$DAV$86$98$12
```

1. 

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS="$";}{
    avg=sqrt(($5-$6)^2)
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,avg
}'|sort -nk7 -t "$"| tail -3
```

Output:

```
4 $ Theekshana $ Second $ DAV $ 97 $ 100$3  
5 $ Teju $ First $ Sangamithra $ 89 $ 100$11  
3 $ Sethu $ First $ DAV $ 86 $ 98$12
```

As you can see there is space before and after `$` sign but for the last column (`avg`) there is no space, please explain why its happening

2)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" | ";OFS="$";}{
    avg=sqrt(($5-$6)^2)
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,avg
}'|sort -nk7 -t "$"| tail -3
```

OUTPUT

```
4$|$Theekshana$|$Second$|$0  
5$|$Teju$|$First$|$0  
6$|$Theekshitha$|$Second$|$0
```

I have not mentiond `|` as the output field separator but still it appears, why is this happening and the difference is zero too

I am just 6 days old in unix,please answer even if its easy

Comment: Arguably this is strictly an awk question and not a bash question at all -- you'd still have the problem if your script was an awk script (starting with `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` and having the body consist only of awk code -- though that would make it responsible for doing the `sort` and `tail` parts in pure awk, so there are additional changes that would be needed)

Answer (score 3):

your field separator is only the pipe symbol, so surrounding whitespace is part of the field definitions and that's what you see in the output.  In combined uses pipe has the regex special meaning and need to be escaped.  In your second case it means space or space is the field separator.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=" *\\| *"; OFS="$"} 
             {d=sqrt(($NF-$(NF-1))^2); $1=$1; 
              print d "\t" $0,d}' file | sort -n | tail -3 | cut -f2-

4$Theekshana$Second$DAV$97$100$3
5$Teju$First$Sangamithra$89$100$11
3$Sethu$First$DAV$86$98$12
```

a slight rewrite will eliminate the number of fields dependency and fixes the format.

Comment: I think you mean pipe symbol, not tab symbol.

Comment: Hah, I meant pipe but typed tab more than once.

Comment: `print d "\t" $0,d}' file | sort -n | tail -3 | cut -f2-` can you please explain 1)why you used d twice in print statement 2)you never mentioned which column to sort on but it still sorted on d 3)" cut -f2-" you didn't mention a delimiter but it still works